# Stop parent scrolling and allow absolute positioned child to overlap parent

Tags: html, jquery, css, css-position

I am trying to create a drop-down type menu and want to position a div so that it overflows all other objects on the page - including parents and parents siblings. At the moment as the div grows it's parent scrolls instead. I tried adding an overflow:hidden parent to the div I want to grow but then it wasn't attached to it's actual parent. This meant when I added extra divs it stayed where it was. I have tried adding z-index but that only works on the direct siblings. Can anybody make it so the yellow div covers all others but still stays attached to it's host div?

```js
/*add text to the absoluteDiv- I want the absolute div to overflow all other divs and parents etc*/
$("body").on("click", "#addStuffToDiv", function() {
  $("#absoluteDiv").append("why is my parent scrolling? <br/>I want to grow over<br/>sibling1 and sibling 2<br/>");
});
/**this will add divs. I want the absoluteDiv to move with it's child host when divs are added **/
$("body").on("click", "#addDivsToSibling", function() {
  $("#sibling1").prepend($("<div>", {
    class: "childDiv"
  }));
});
```

```css
.sibling {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: auto;
}

.childDiv {
  background-color: aqua;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.childHost {
  background-color: orange;
}

#absoluteDiv {
  min-width: 150px;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: 150;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <!--- button that adds info to the div I want to grow -->
  <button id="addStuffToDiv">add stuff to the div</button><button id="addDivsToSibling">add divs</button>
  <!--this is parent - when information is added to absoluteDiv I don't want this parent to scroll but instead the yellow box to overflow -->
  <div id="sibling1" class="sibling">
    <div class="childDiv"></div>
    <div class="childDiv childHost">
      <!--when text is added to this div I want it to grow over it's parent and not have parent scroll -->
      <div id="absoluteDiv" class="">some Random text <br/>I want to grow over<br/>sibling1 and sibling 2<br/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="childDiv"></div>
    <div class="childDiv"></div>
    <div class="childDiv"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="sibling">
    <div class="childDiv"></div>
    <div class="childDiv"></div>
    <div class="childDiv"></div>
    <div class="childDiv"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: If `column-count` in the `absoluteDiv` helps?

Comment: Thanks for that but I'm looking for a way to make the absoluteDiv cover all others and stop it's parent scrolling. The text is just there to add something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you mean... Just remove `overflow: auto;` from the .sibling class.

```js
/*add text to the absoluteDiv- I want the absolute div to overflow all other divs and parents etc*/
$("body").on("click", "#addStuffToDiv", function() {
  $("#absoluteDiv").append("why is my parent scrolling? <br/>I want to grow over<br/>sibling1 and sibling 2<br/>");
});
/**this will add divs. I want the absoluteDiv to move with it's child host when divs are added **/
$("body").on("click", "#addDivsToSibling", function() {
  $("#sibling1").prepend($("<div>", {
    class: "childDiv"
  }));
});
```

```css
.sibling {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  
}

.childDiv {
  background-color: aqua;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.childHost {
  background-color: orange;
}

#absoluteDiv {
  min-width: 150px;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: 150;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <!--- button that adds info to the div I want to grow -->
  <button id="addStuffToDiv">add stuff to the div</button><button id="addDivsToSibling">add divs</button>
  <!--this is parent - when information is added to absoluteDiv I don't want this parent to scroll but instead the yellow box to overflow -->
  <div id="sibling1" class="sibling">
    <div class="childDiv"></div>
    <div class="childDiv childHost" id="test">
      <!--when text is added to this div I want it to grow over it's parent and not have parent scroll -->
      <div id="absoluteDiv" class="">some Random text <br/>I want to grow over<br/>sibling1 and sibling 2<br/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="childDiv"></div>
    <div class="childDiv"></div>
    <div class="childDiv"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="sibling">
    <div class="childDiv"></div>
    <div class="childDiv"></div>
    <div class="childDiv"></div>
    <div class="childDiv"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks. That works. I know it's a tall order but can you find a way to do it with overflow:auto still there? Some of the internal divs will be floating and overflow:auto keeps them inside the parent.

Comment: @bevan7 if you can add an id to those specific divs you want `overflow:auto` with you could just call the id in CSS and apply it to them.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to change the display to flex and that seems to work. Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: No problem! glad to have helped.